# How do I breed a Sakura Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

There's a new Sakura Dragon in the market with the elements Plant, Earth and Fire. Sounds like it's limited time.

How do I get a Sakura Dragon egg and how will I know when I get one? Approximately how rare are they? How long do I have to breed one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Sakura_Dragon):

> The Sakura Dragon can be bred by using a combination of dragons whose elements include plant, earth, and fire.  The in game splash message indicated that you must be level 11+ to breed this dragon.

You may have bred a Sakura dragon if you get a breed time of 10 hours, but you will have to wait till you see the egg to be sure, since it could be a Lava dragon as well.  The egg is brown egg with three cherry blossoms on it, like this:

The sakura dragon is only breedable until **May 3rd**.

[image]

Comment: Any idea how rare they are? Clover dragons were crazy rare, bloom dragons weren't very rare, I'm wondering where this one falls

Comment: I've had about 3 failed attempts with a possible success in the hopper.  I'll let you know pending that result.

Comment: I am currently on my 4th Lava Dragon. I would classify this baby as a Rare breeding.. I have had Countless Flower dragons. I am breeding a Plant and a Lava for what its worth.

Answer (score 1):

Flower and Tree, when the breeding time is 10 hrs, chances are its a sakura dragon. The egg will be brown with 3 flowers on it.

Comment: Very low chances, as pointed to in the article listed in EBongo's answer. While this combination does seem to be the best combination, its still about a 10% chance at best to get this dragon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it matters what lvl you are I'm 22 and I have breed panlong sun moon and bloom so it shouldn't matter but yes I would highly recommend tree and flower because they both have play in them and they have the other two elements fire and earth and the way to breed dodo is to go chrome and earth

Comment: Fully agree with Mario and I like your thought process. Got both of them using your combo's

Answer (score 0):

I'm level 21 at the moment (I really don't know if level matters) and I used tree dragon in the first slot and poison dragon in the second slot for breeding and I got it on the first try.

Comment: Pretty sure level only matters so far as you have to have dragons of the 3 elements you need

Answer (score -1):

Poison and earth is one way while Tree and Flower is also available. You can also use Tree and Poison. In the breeding cave the bred ding time will be 10 hours. That is also the time it takes to incubate the egg. The Sakura dragon. Is not the only dragon with a ten hour breeding time. So to be Shure you have to wait until you see the egg. The egg should be an earth brown with 3 light pink flowers blooming on it.